# Single for-loop Into Mult Columns(JAVA)

Tags: java, for-loop, multiple-columns

I haven an assignment for school and I'm a beginner into Java. I did the ASCII char loops like I needed to, but I want it to look pretty.

How do I make a single for-loop into multiple columns to show up on the output screen without having to scroll?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   for (int i = 32; i <= 126; i++) 
       System.out.println((char) i);
}//end main
```

Comment: Please explain more what you're trying to do. ASCII `char` loops? Is this trying to print out a table of the printable ASCII character set?

Comment: @chrylis Yes kind of like a table, but I just need 3 columns to make it look pretty. I can add lines and such myself. I just can't figure out how to make it split into 3 or 4 columns.

Comment: See my answer, and just adjust my 8 columns to whatever you think looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `System.out.println`, just use `System.out.print`, and on each iteration through the loop, check to see whether `i % 8 == 7` (or the equivalent for some other line length). If it is, print a newline; otherwise, print a tab or some spaces.